# grayed out ASP.NET MVC dialog after upgrading to SignalR 2.2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

The demo works great for me on this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/417502/Online-Whiteboard-using-HTML-and-SignalR. That said, I upgraded to SignalR 2.2 from 1.0 RC, and to jquery 2.2 from 1.6.4.

It works fine, except that when I first start up the whole screen and initial dialog are grayed out. I can still login if I tab to the "Join" button and hit enter, but it is not intuitive because normally a user would want to simply click on the Join button.

So far I have tried enabling the whole display by calling this in JoinHub():

```
$("#btnJoin").prop('disabled', false);
```

And,

```
$("ui-widget-overlay").prop('disabled', false);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? TIA.

Please see this link for a screen shot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeiA7.jpg

Comment: do you see any error in your browser console window?

Comment: No, there is no error.  First, in whiteboard_1.js, it calls "$(document).ready(function () {" which then calls toggleBG1().  toggleBG1() then calls toggleBG2(), which goes back to toggleBG1(), and so on indefinitely.

Comment: The whiteboard_1.js code is the same for the SignalR 1.0 RC and the SignalR 2.2 code, so I'm not sure why it works fine in the 1.0 RC version but just loops indefinitely with the screen grayed out in the 2.2 version.